# Kestrel HTTPS: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate

Tags: https, certificate, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

Having background errors thrown by Kestrel but not preventing user to use web server properly in HTTPS mode.

Those errors are occuring every 20minutes roughly even if there is no activity on web server.

```
"System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionFilter.<OnConnectionAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionFilter.<OnConnectionAsync>d__6.MoveNext()<---"
```

Dependencies for this web server

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite": "1.0.0", 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource": "1.1.0", 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0"
```

Comment: did you solve this issue?